# Selecting a substring if it's not an integer

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting two substrings from the same column, in this instance it's a UK postcode.

What I'd like to do is only select the second if it is NOT an integer.

Ultimately I'm going to be writing both substrings (the second if it's not an integer) to a new column.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(postcode,1,1) AS one, SUBSTRING(postcode,2,1) AS two
```

Can I wrap an IF Statement around the second substring?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(postcode,1,1) AS one, IF NOT INT(SUBSTRING(postcode,2,1)) AS two
```

Many thanks

Comment: You want `case when ... else ... end`: [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html)

Comment: You cannot change the output table at runtime, you can however make it select `null` instead with `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible (assuming you are happy with 2 columns coming back).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(postcode,1,1) AS one, IF(SUBSTRING(postcode,2,1) REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$', NULL, SUBSTRING(postcode,2,1)) AS two 
FROM Postcodes
```

Might get a bit more messy if you want to cope with more complex postcodes such as EC1A 1BB , depending on whether you want the A returned or not and under what circumstances.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help. I was playing around with the CASE statement but couldn't get the regex to work. This is perfect. Cheers!